# Check box use in Google Sheets

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to use the Google Sheets to sort the column in descending order when a checkbox is enabled

I have tried assigning the value to the sheets and import the application it should be interfering into the data but couldn't resolve the issue

`if(A2,FILTER(A3:A,A3:A>0),0)`, Assuming A2 is the checkbox presence

Also tried `SORT` function but both are creating errors like Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A4.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
=IF(B1=1, SORT(A3:A, 1, 1), {A3:A})
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIL6q73zdkHtO9P-co-OMhobawKlLf2bH2P017dbK48/edit#gid=0)**